# org-latex-preview error on Windows: file was not generated please adjust dvisvgm part of org-latex-preview-process-alist

Tags: org-mode, latex, eshell

I have used `org-mode` before in *Linux* to generate *LaTeX* fragments very smoothly. I am using [`dvisvgm`](https://dvisvgm.de).

Now, I have switched to *Windows*. I keep getting the error "**file orgtex00000.dvi was not generated please adjust dvisvgm part of org-latex-preview-process-alist**".

The *LaTeX* file is produced but not be converted to *DVI*. I traced back the error and the only thing I see is that *Emacs* writes my user name on *LaTeX* file path in a strange way: instead of "**user.name**", it becomes "**USER~1.NA**".

Is that normal on *Windows*? How can I get the exact command that is spawned from *Emacs* to debug more?

### EDIT

I have the following setting for my `org-latex-preview-process-alist`

```el
((dvipng :programs
         ("latex" "dvipng")
         :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
         (1.0 . 1.0)
         :latex-compiler
         ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
         :image-converter
         ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f")
         :transparent-image-converter
         ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -bg Transparent -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
          ("latex" "dvisvgm")
          :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
          (1.7 . 1.5)
          :latex-compiler
          ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvisvgm %f --no-fonts --exact-bbox --scale=%S --output=%O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
              ("latex" "convert")
              :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
              (1.0 . 1.0)
              :latex-compiler
              ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
              :image-converter
              ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

Comment: What *does* the `dvisvgm` part of `org-latex-preview-process-alist` look like? Do `C-h v org-latex-preview-process-alist` and edit your question to add the value (you might as well add the whole thing, not just the `dvisvgm` part).

Comment: OK, that looks unchanged from the default. Check the buffer `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*` and see if that tells you anything of interest. Feel free to add it to your question if you need more help.

Comment: @NickD This buffers shows "cannot find file ../../../USER" error. This is the part before tilda in I believe (see my username format above).